# Having trouble with a custom geom that transforms single row aesthetics to multiple rows for polygonGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to create my own geom and stat that plots little 'sticks' at xy positions on the panel. The sticks are parameterised by their center point (x and y), length, aspect and angle. I want to be able to provide a dataframe to ggplot that has one row per 'stick' with a column for each parameter.

I have created the function below, which given the parameters above resturns a dataframe of x and y positions for the 4 corners of the 'stick'. Importantly, it takes one single row and expands it to 4 rows.

```
rects <- function(x, y, angle, length, aspect){

  angle <- angle * (pi/180)

  # Compute x_start and x_end of each rectangle (assuming zero width)
  xs <- x - cos(angle) * length/2
  xe <- x + cos(angle) * length/2
  ys <- y - sin(angle) * length/2
  ye <- y + sin(angle) * length/2

  # Compute the x and y coordinates of the 4 corners of the rectangle when the
  # width is considered.
  p1x <- xe - ((length/aspect/2) * cos((pi/2) - angle))
  p1y <- ye + ((length/aspect/2) * sin((pi/2) - angle))
  p2x <- xe + ((length/aspect/2) * cos((pi/2) - angle))
  p2y <- ye - ((length/aspect/2) * sin((pi/2) - angle))
  p3x <- xs + ((length/aspect/2) * cos((pi/2) - angle))
  p3y <- ys - ((length/aspect/2) * sin((pi/2) - angle))
  p4x <- xs - ((length/aspect/2) * cos((pi/2) - angle))
  p4y <- ys + ((length/aspect/2) * sin((pi/2) - angle))

  tibble(x = c(p1x, p2x, p3x, p4x),
         y = c(p1y, p2y, p3y, p4y))

  }
```

My stat then uses `purrr::map_dfr()` to take the data in the one-row-per stick format and transform it into a dataframe that has 4 times as many rows and only x and y columns.

```
StatNematicRect <- 
  ggplot2::ggproto(`_class` = "StatNematicRect",
                   `_inherit` = ggplot2::Stat,
                   required_aes = c("x", "y", "angle", "length", "aspect"),
                   compute_group = function(data, scales){
                     purrr::pmap_dfr(.l = list(data$x, data$y, data$angle, data$length, data$aspect),
                                     .f = rects)

                                    }
)
```

My geom then plots the sticks using `polygonGrob` and is done with `draw_group` in order to make the polygon 'sticks' separate

```
GeomNematicRect <- 
  ggplot2::ggproto("GeomNematicRect",
                   ggplot2::GeomPolygon,
                   required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                   default_aes = ggplot2::aes(colour=1, fill="grey80", size=0.2, linetype=1, alpha=1),
                   draw_key = ggplot2::draw_key_polygon,

                   draw_group = function(data, panel_params, coord) {
                     n <- nrow(data)
                     if (n <= 2) return(grid::nullGrob())

                     coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)

                     # A polygon can only have a single colour, fill, etc, so take from first row
                     first_row <- coords[1, , drop = FALSE]

                     grid::polygonGrob(
                       x = coords$x,
                       y = coords$y,
                       default.units = "native",
                       gp = grid::gpar(
                         col = first_row$colour,
                         fill = scales::alpha(first_row$fill, first_row$alpha),
                         lwd = first_row$size * .pt,
                         lty = first_row$linetype
                         )
                     )
                     }
                   )
```

This means I need to provide a group aesthetic when I make the call to `geom_nematic_rect()` in order to print each polygon as its own entity, rather than one continuous mess, so I end up having to make a unique id per row of the dataframe and passing that to the group aesthetic which just feels messy and unnecessary.

Is there a way to re-write this code so that it isn't done needing the group aesthetic. I played around with `draw_panel` rather than `draw_group` but couldn't get other aesthetics like fill and colour to map to the 4 x longer dataframe after the transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following adaptations to your ggproto environments. It relies heavily on the assumption that each row will spawn 4 and exactly 4 new rows.

With regards to the Stat, I changed the computation from the group to the panel, which in general should be more efficient. Mostly the thing I added is matching up the new rows with the old rows.

```
StatNematicRect <- 
  ggplot2::ggproto(
    `_class` = "StatNematicRect",
    `_inherit` = ggplot2::Stat,
    required_aes = c("x", "y", "angle", "length", "aspect"),
    compute_panel = function(data, scales){
      old_data <- data
      data <- purrr::pmap_dfr(.l = list(data$x, data$y, data$angle, data$length, data$aspect),
                              .f = rects)
      seq <- seq_len(nrow(old_data))
      id <- rep(seq, each = 4)
      old_data$x <- NULL
      old_data$y <- NULL
      old_data <- old_data[id,]
      cbind(data, old_data)
    }
  )
```

For the Geom part, you were pretty close, but I think you might have overlooked the `id`/`id.lengths` part of `?grid::polygonGrob()` to divide the rows into rectangles. Also here I went from group drawing to panel drawing to avoid uneccesary looping.

```
GeomNematicRect <- 
  ggplot2::ggproto(
    "GeomNematicRect",
    ggplot2::GeomPolygon,
    required_aes = c("x", "y"),
    default_aes = ggplot2::aes(colour=1, fill="grey80", size=0.2, linetype=1, alpha=1),
    draw_key = ggplot2::draw_key_polygon,
    draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord) {
      n <- nrow(data)
      
      coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
      
      firsts <- seq(1, nrow(coords), by = 4)
      firsts <- coords[firsts,]
      
      grid::polygonGrob(
        x = coords$x,
        y = coords$y,
        default.units = "native",
        id = rep(seq_len(nrow(firsts)), each = 4),
        gp = grid::gpar(
          col = firsts$colour,
          fill = scales::alpha(firsts$fill, firsts$alpha),
          lwd = firsts$size * .pt,
          lty = firsts$linetype
        )
      )
    }
  )
```

A small demonstration:

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(n),
  y = rnorm(n),
  col = sample(LETTERS[1:4], n, TRUE),
  angle = runif(n, 0, 360),
  length = runif(n, 0.5, 1.5),
  aspect = runif(n, 0.5, 1.5)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, angle = angle, length = length, aspect = aspect)) +
  geom_nematic_rect(aes(fill = col))
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for this really hepful response. I have been able to make my own working version. The one thing I dont understand is, how does the `data`  passed to  the `draw_panel` argument already have the fill colour specification repeated for every 4 rows? I can't see where that is done. I assume all non-required aesthetics will also be repeated for every 4 rows?

Comment: It is the `old_data <- old_data[id,]` line in the Stat methods that matches up the old data with every row in the newly calculated data. It basically copies every variable of the old data parallel to the new data (expect for `x` and `y`, which we've removed previously).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. For completeness, I have modified the code to create the ID variable in the stat `comput_panel` function so it will work regardless of the polygon created and the number of points it is made out of. 

`data %>% dplyr::mutate(my_id = dplyr::row_number(), new = purrr::pmap(list(x, y, angle, length, aspect), rects)) %>% dplyr::select(-x, -y) %>% tidyr::unnest(new)` 


In the geom you can then pass `coords$my_id` to the `polygonGrob` `id` argument generate the dataframe of `firsts` with `firsts <- coords %>% dplyr::group_by(my_id) %>% dplyr::summarize_all(dplyr::first)`

Comment: Yeah that seems a sensible way to make it more robust. I'm not fluent in tidyverse so I'm unsure what all these functions mean.